# clang-tidy default checks (unknown origin)

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

My clang-tidy seems to have some hardcoded options I cannot get rid of, without any `.clang-file` (as seen in `--explain-config` below):

```
clang-tidy --checks=-* --dump-config
---
Checks:          'clang-diagnostic-*,clang-analyzer-*,-*'
WarningsAsErrors: ''
HeaderFilterRegex: ''
AnalyzeTemporaryDtors: false
FormatStyle:     none
User:            <my user>
CheckOptions:
  llvm-else-after-return.WarnOnConditionVariables: 'false'
  modernize-loop-convert.MinConfidence: reasonable
  modernize-replace-auto-ptr.IncludeStyle: llvm
  cert-str34-c.DiagnoseSignedUnsignedCharComparisons: 'false'
  google-readability-namespace-comments.ShortNamespaceLines: '10'
  cert-err33-c.CheckedFunctions: '::aligned_alloc;::asctime_s;::at_quick_exit;::atexit;::bsearch;::bsearch_s;::btowc;::c16rtomb;::c32rtomb;::calloc;::clock;::cnd_broadcast;::cnd_init;::cnd_signal;::cnd_timedwait;::cnd_wait;::ctime_s;::fclose;::fflush;::fgetc;::fgetpos;::fgets;::fgetwc;::fopen;::fopen_s;::fprintf;::fprintf_s;::fputc;::fputs;::fputwc;::fputws;::fread;::freopen;::freopen_s;::fscanf;::fscanf_s;::fseek;::fsetpos;::ftell;::fwprintf;::fwprintf_s;::fwrite;::fwscanf;::fwscanf_s;::getc;::getchar;::getenv;::getenv_s;::gets_s;::getwc;::getwchar;::gmtime;::gmtime_s;::localtime;::localtime_s;::malloc;::mbrtoc16;::mbrtoc32;::mbsrtowcs;::mbsrtowcs_s;::mbstowcs;::mbstowcs_s;::memchr;::mktime;::mtx_init;::mtx_lock;::mtx_timedlock;::mtx_trylock;::mtx_unlock;::printf_s;::putc;::putwc;::raise;::realloc;::remove;::rename;::scanf;::scanf_s;::setlocale;::setvbuf;::signal;::snprintf;::snprintf_s;::sprintf;::sprintf_s;::sscanf;::sscanf_s;::strchr;::strerror_s;::strftime;::strpbrk;::strrchr;::strstr;::strtod;::strtof;::strtoimax;::strtok;::strtok_s;::strtol;::strtold;::strtoll;::strtoul;::strtoull;::strtoumax;::strxfrm;::swprintf;::swprintf_s;::swscanf;::swscanf_s;::thrd_create;::thrd_detach;::thrd_join;::thrd_sleep;::time;::timespec_get;::tmpfile;::tmpfile_s;::tmpnam;::tmpnam_s;::tss_create;::tss_get;::tss_set;::ungetc;::ungetwc;::vfprintf;::vfprintf_s;::vfscanf;::vfscanf_s;::vfwprintf;::vfwprintf_s;::vfwscanf;::vfwscanf_s;::vprintf_s;::vscanf;::vscanf_s;::vsnprintf;::vsnprintf_s;::vsprintf;::vsprintf_s;::vsscanf;::vsscanf_s;::vswprintf;::vswprintf_s;::vswscanf;::vswscanf_s;::vwprintf_s;::vwscanf;::vwscanf_s;::wcrtomb;::wcschr;::wcsftime;::wcspbrk;::wcsrchr;::wcsrtombs;::wcsrtombs_s;::wcsstr;::wcstod;::wcstof;::wcstoimax;::wcstok;::wcstok_s;::wcstol;::wcstold;::wcstoll;::wcstombs;::wcstombs_s;::wcstoul;::wcstoull;::wcstoumax;::wcsxfrm;::wctob;::wctrans;::wctype;::wmemchr;::wprintf_s;::wscanf;::wscanf_s;'
  cert-oop54-cpp.WarnOnlyIfThisHasSuspiciousField: 'false'
  cert-dcl16-c.NewSuffixes: 'L;LL;LU;LLU'
  google-readability-braces-around-statements.ShortStatementLines: '1'
  cppcoreguidelines-non-private-member-variables-in-classes.IgnoreClassesWithAllMemberVariablesBeingPublic: 'true'
  google-readability-namespace-comments.SpacesBeforeComments: '2'
  modernize-loop-convert.MaxCopySize: '16'
  modernize-pass-by-value.IncludeStyle: llvm
  modernize-use-nullptr.NullMacros: 'NULL'
  llvm-qualified-auto.AddConstToQualified: 'false'
  modernize-loop-convert.NamingStyle: CamelCase
  llvm-else-after-return.WarnOnUnfixable: 'false'
  google-readability-function-size.StatementThreshold: '800'
...
```

Where are those coming of and how can I get rid of them ?
I discovered this by trying hard to overwrite `readability-braces-around-statements.ShortNamespaceLines`, but the default `google-readability-braces-around-statements` always win, unmovable.

No explanation when asked explicitly:

```
clang-tidy --dump-config --explain-config
'clang-analyzer-apiModeling.Errno' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-apiModeling.StdCLibraryFunctions' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-apiModeling.TrustNonnull' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-apiModeling.TrustReturnsNonnull' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-apiModeling.google.GTest' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-apiModeling.llvm.CastValue' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-apiModeling.llvm.ReturnValue' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-core.CallAndMessage' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-core.CallAndMessageModeling' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-core.DivideZero' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-core.DynamicTypePropagation' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-core.NonNullParamChecker' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-core.NonnilStringConstants' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-core.NullDereference' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-core.StackAddrEscapeBase' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-core.StackAddressEscape' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-core.UndefinedBinaryOperatorResult' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-core.VLASize' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-core.builtin.BuiltinFunctions' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-core.builtin.NoReturnFunctions' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-core.uninitialized.ArraySubscript' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-core.uninitialized.Assign' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-core.uninitialized.Branch' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-core.uninitialized.CapturedBlockVariable' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-core.uninitialized.UndefReturn' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-cplusplus.InnerPointer' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-cplusplus.Move' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-cplusplus.NewDelete' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-cplusplus.NewDeleteLeaks' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-cplusplus.PlacementNew' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-cplusplus.PureVirtualCall' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-cplusplus.SelfAssignment' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-cplusplus.SmartPtrModeling' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-cplusplus.StringChecker' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-cplusplus.VirtualCallModeling' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-deadcode.DeadStores' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-fuchsia.HandleChecker' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-nullability.NullPassedToNonnull' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-nullability.NullReturnedFromNonnull' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-nullability.NullabilityBase' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-nullability.NullableDereferenced' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-nullability.NullablePassedToNonnull' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-nullability.NullableReturnedFromNonnull' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-optin.cplusplus.UninitializedObject' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-optin.cplusplus.VirtualCall' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-optin.mpi.MPI-Checker' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-optin.osx.OSObjectCStyleCast' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-optin.osx.cocoa.localizability.EmptyLocalizationContextChecker' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-optin.osx.cocoa.localizability.NonLocalizedStringChecker' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-optin.performance.GCDAntipattern' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-optin.performance.Padding' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-optin.portability.UnixAPI' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.API' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.MIG' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.NSOrCFErrorDerefChecker' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.NumberObjectConversion' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.OSObjectRetainCount' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.ObjCProperty' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.SecKeychainAPI' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.AtSync' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.AutoreleaseWrite' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.ClassRelease' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.Dealloc' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.IncompatibleMethodTypes' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.Loops' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.MissingSuperCall' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.NSAutoreleasePool' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.NSError' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.NilArg' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.NonNilReturnValue' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.ObjCGenerics' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.RetainCount' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.RetainCountBase' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.RunLoopAutoreleaseLeak' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.SelfInit' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.SuperDealloc' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.UnusedIvars' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.VariadicMethodTypes' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.coreFoundation.CFError' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.coreFoundation.CFNumber' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.coreFoundation.CFRetainRelease' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.coreFoundation.containers.OutOfBounds' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-osx.coreFoundation.containers.PointerSizedValues' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-security.FloatLoopCounter' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.DeprecatedOrUnsafeBufferHandling' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.SecuritySyntaxChecker' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.UncheckedReturn' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.bcmp' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.bcopy' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.bzero' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.decodeValueOfObjCType' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.getpw' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.gets' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.mkstemp' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.mktemp' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.rand' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.strcpy' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.vfork' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-unix.API' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-unix.DynamicMemoryModeling' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-unix.Malloc' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-unix.MallocSizeof' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-unix.MismatchedDeallocator' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-unix.Vfork' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-unix.cstring.BadSizeArg' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-unix.cstring.CStringModeling' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-unix.cstring.NullArg' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-valist.CopyToSelf' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-valist.Uninitialized' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-valist.Unterminated' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-valist.ValistBase' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-webkit.NoUncountedMemberChecker' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-webkit.RefCntblBaseVirtualDtor' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
'clang-analyzer-webkit.UncountedLambdaCapturesChecker' is enabled in the clang-tidy binary.
```

Version:

```
clang-tidy --version
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 15.0.6
  Optimized build.
  Default target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  Host CPU: tigerlake
```

**Update**

The above example does not involve any `.clang-tidy` file.

`clang-tidy --fix-errors` seems to work with the following `.clang-tidy`, even if `google-readability-braces-around-statements.ShortStatementLines` stays 1 in the dumped config.

```
Checks: hicpp-*, readability-identifier-naming,

CheckOptions:
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.ClassCase, value: CamelCase}

# readability-braces-around-statements
# also see clang-format:InsertBraces
# aliases: hicpp-braces-around-statements, google-readability-braces-around-statements
# TODO: google-readability-braces-around-statements.ShortStatementLines is always there (--dump-config), 1, but won't be applied
  - { key: google-readability-braces-around-statements.ShortStatementLines, value: 3}
  - { key: hicpp-braces-around-statements.ShortStatementLines, value: 3}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run `clang-tidy.exe --checks=-* --dump-config`, I get the same output as you do:

- The list of about 20 `CheckOptions` can be ignored, because these
  options are for checks that are disabled.
- The only "checks" still *apparently* enabled are `clang-diagnostic-*,clang-analyzer-*`.

These are "diagnostics" which -- unlike regular checks -- depend on corresponding clang compiler warnings being enabled as well.  I.E. pass  `-- -Weverything` at the end of your `clang-tidy` command line to enable all clang compiler warnings so that `clang-diagnostic-*,clang-analyzer-*` can notice them.  Or you can enable only some clang warnings.

Anyway, when I take away the `--dump-config` parameter and run `clang-tidy.exe --checks=-* mysourcefile.cpp`, I get `Error: no checks enabled`.  So `clang-tidy` is honoring `--checks=-*`, but the help text generated by `--dump-config` appears to be incorrect.

Running `clang-tidy.exe --checks=-*,clang-diagnostic-*,clang-analyzer-* mysourcefile.cpp -- -Weverything` produces the expected `clang-diagnostic` and `clang-analyzer` messages.

Your `.clang-tidy` file that includes the line:

`Checks: hicpp-*, readability-identifier-naming,`

should probably be modified so the line looks like this:

`Checks: '-*,hicpp-*,readability-identifier-naming'`

In this way, you are explicitly disabling all the regular clang-tidy checks before explicitly enabling only the `hicpp` and `readability-identifier-naming` checks.

Comment: Thank you, but the phenomenon happens without any `.clang-tidy`. The question is not related to that file.

Comment: @Liviu - I updated my answer to disregard the `.clang-tidy` file.  It appears the help text from the `--dump-config` parameter is incorrect when it claims some checks are still enabled.

Comment: I can accept your answer except for a couple of questions: 1. "In this way, you are explicitly disabling all the regular clang-tidy checks" - why would I do that ?

Comment: You say "the help text generated by --dump-config appears to be incorrect.". But if in my `.clang-format` file I comment last line only, this will be immediately applied: `google-readability-braces-around-statements.ShortStatementLines: '1'`. So, to me, not only the text seems incorrect: that default `google-readability-braces-around-statements` option is REALLY applied (instead of the one from the file). Thank you!

Comment: I also tried: `$ clang-tidy -config="{Checks: hicpp-*,readability-identifier-naming, CheckOptions: [{key: google-readability-braces-around-statements.ShortStatementLines, value: 3}]}" --fix-errors *.cpp -- -std=c++11`
`<command-line-config>:1:18: error: unknown key 'readability-identifier-naming'
{Checks: hicpp-*,readability-identifier-naming, CheckOptions: [{key: google-readability-braces-around-statements.ShortStatementLines, value: 3}]}
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: invalid configuration specified.
invalid argument`

Comment: @Liviu disabling all of the Clang Tidy default checks first before specifying one or more specific checks allows you to run Clang Tidy incrementally.  This way you can review the warnings or fixes of only a few checks at a time, before running more checks.  Some fix options are best run before others, such as running checks which set default member initializers before `modernize-use-equals-default`.  As for `invalid configuration specified` I suggest using a `.clang-tidy` file with a format similar to the one in the LLVM project on GitHub (i.e. no curly braces).

Comment: the invalid configuration is on command line call, so without `.clang-tidy`.  Anyway, thank you! This has gone too far, I believe